# Read form more files using awk, how?

Tags: awk

I would like to read more input files with awk. In every file in my folder starting with ftp_dst_ I want to run this little awk script.

```
for i in ftp_dst_*; 
    do

gawk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" -v fa="$fa" -v fb="$fb" -v max="$max" '
BEGIN{
        FS=" ";
        OFS="\t";
    }
    {
        if ($8 == "nrecvdatabytes_")
        {
                b=a;
                a=$1;           

                if (b!=0)
                {               
                fa=a-b; 
                    if (fa>max && fa!=0)
                    {
                        max=fa;
                    }   
                }           
        }   
    }
    END{
        print "lol";
        #print flowid, max;
    }
'./ftp_dst_*
done
```

So now ftp_dst_5, ftp_dst_6, ftp_dst_7 are in the folder so I should get 3 lines with lol in the command line. Of course this "print lol" is only a try, I want to get 3 values from the 3 files. 
So how can I read from all these files using awk?

Comment: have you tried to change the ./ftp_dst_* on the next last row to $i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using a glob in the argument, all the files are taken together as if they were one file. Without the shell `for` loop, you would get output one time. Since you have the `for` loop, you should be getting the output three times. Part of your problem may be that you need a space after the closing single quote or you may need to change the argument to `"$i"` as Karl Nordström suggested if you want each file to be considered separately.